# Masonry lasy load gaps

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

some images slightly incorrectly positioned vertically. Even if you put settimeout, nothing will change.

Javascript:

```
$(this).addClass("k-lazy-loaded"), $(this).trigger("k-image-loaded", $(this));

$("#grid").masonry(this);
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="grid"><li>...</li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.grid li a,
.grid li img {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
```

[view screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfDmU.jpg)

Comment: You tagged `css`, do you have any `css` code that might be affecting placement?

Comment: Sure. I wrote css.

Comment: Impossible to tell for sure, but is it possible that the white line is in the image?

Comment: I thought so too, but no :( these margins almost under or over any picture appears. Sometimes as the top and bottom of the indentation